# Problem in Artboard Arrange in Illustrator after duplicate

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, illustrator-scripting

I am doing a presentation in Illustrator using multiple artboards and after I finished my work the client needed some changes made.

I need to add one Artboard next in between of the presentation. But when I duplicate to rtboard next to that page the order is changing  , it is coming last page in artboard arrangement.

So I have to go to artboard then I put page is upward, So is there any solution to add new page next in between  that without changing Order

Comment: I tried to edit it best I could but I still don't understand quite exactly what you are trying to ask @Uvais Kp

Comment: what file format are you exporting this presentation to? Why did you tag it "illustrator-scripting", is there any automation involved?

Comment: I had the same problem and it appears that software needed an update from Creative Suite. Once update artboards went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter artboard names and order using the **Artboard Panel** (View > Artboards) in Adobe Illustrator. This changes their general stacking order but will not actually move any artboard directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to change the order that's what you got to do:

When you duplicate an artboard the new one goes to the last position in the stack.

Go to the Artboards panel and drag that new artboard to the desired stack position.

See the image below:

[image]